# WCF Rest service receives null value from SOAPUI

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I am trying to test my wcf rest serice via soapui in my development environment, although my service is being hit but the parameter always receives null value.

I am passing string xml from SOAPUI using POST method but I always get null in xmlString argument of the XMLData method.I tried various combinations in the SOAPUI but everytime I receive a null value.

My intention is to send the xml parameter to another service in intranet.

Here's my Service Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPayGService
{
    [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method="POST",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml,ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,UriTemplate="XMLData")]
    void XMLData(string xmlString);
}
```

Here's the implementation of the above service contract

```
public class PayGService : IPayGService
{
    public void XMLData(string xmlString)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request =     (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://10.77.146.113:8081/PAGUIManager/rest/response");
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlString);
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.Method = "POST";
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string responseStr = new     StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}


Here's what I'm trying to post from SOAP UI "<![CDATA[<response>    <requestType>CC</requestType><pagTransId>CSS1234</pagTransId>    <pgTransId>PG12345</pgTransId><amount>1200</amount><Status>SUCCESS</Status>        <message>Payment Successful</message><MSISDIN>8888853991</MSISDIN><bankRef>123bank</bankRef>    <bankCode>123</bankCode><checkSum>%%%%%%%^^^^&&& </checkSum>    <cartInfo>8888853991:001:100</cartInfo></response>]]"
```

[Here's the SOAPUI Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlhR5.jpg)

Comment: What are you posting from `SoapUI`?

Comment: Edit it into the question, then remove the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution will help you:

> In the Request Properties panel, there is option Max Size, if you set this to, lets say, 1048576 (1MB), SoapUI won't load more than 1MB of result into memory.
>
> If you use this with Dump File property in the same panel, you can easily dump complete response to the file, thus avoiding memory usage.

Comment: I tried setting the MaxSize property but its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is not with the service itself, but with what `SoapUI` is sending.

I made a small test service with the same `OperationContract` as in your question. Then I create a project in `SoapUI` to test it. This raw xml works when sending it from `SoapUI`:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:XMLData>
         <tem:xmlString><![CDATA[<response>    <requestType>CC</requestType><pagTransId>CSS1234</pagTransId>    <pgTransId>PG12345</pgTransId><amount>1200</amount><Status>SUCCESS</Status>        <message>Payment Successful</message><MSISDIN>8888853991</MSISDIN><bankRef>123bank</bankRef>    <bankCode>123</bankCode><checkSum>%%%%%%%^^^^&&& </checkSum>    <cartInfo>8888853991:001:100</cartInfo></response>]]></tem:xmlString>
      </tem:XMLData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My `SoapUI` is an older version than yours, so I don't know exactly where you should test raw xml. But I could see a `Raw` tab in your screenshot, so maybe that would be the place. You may have to change the `tem` namespace so it matches with the namespace you have on the service.

Comment: I tried with the solution you said, however the solution didnt work for me as the raw xml is not able to pass through the service method "XMLData". Initially I was trying to pass parameter as a string but to implement your solution I created a class and indicated the namespace but still got null value in the parameter when the debug hit the code.